# java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm having an issue with the error code "java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server." I'm trying to use JDBC to establish a connection with the database, the credentials are correctly spelled. Could you please help me to check what could be failing in this project?

```
package com.example.daily.db;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.example.daily.R;
import com.mysql.cj.protocol.Resultset;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class controler extends AppCompatActivity {
    private controler controlador;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tercera);
        controlador = new controler();
    }
    public static void micontroler (){

        String usuario = "root";
        String password = "Prueb@1";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/daily_db";
        Connection conexion;
        Statement statement;
        Resultset rs;

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }


        try {
            conexion = DriverManager.getConnection(url,usuario,password);
            statement = conexion.createStatement();
            statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO USUARIOS(EMAIL,NOMBRES,APELLIDOS,APODO,FECHA_NACIMIENTO) VALUES ('Teste','TESTn','TESTa','TESTp','14/06/22')");


        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I checked the connection, rewrote the code, added the controller to the manifest.

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally this issue occurs when the connection string becomes wrong. Can you check if the connection string formed is of the correct format.

The expected connection string for a mysql jdbc connection will be as below,

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/daily_db?user=root&password=Prueb@1&serverTimezone=UTC
```

Please refer https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-jdbc-url-format.html for more details regarding the connection string.

Also please make sure the DB is up and running on the ports provided in your code, i..e, localhost:3306.